# Matrix inverse LQ

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

i think it's very simple question, but i'm stuck.
$$A=LQ$$ **but, why?** $$(A)^{-1}\neq{Q^T}L^{-1}$$

$Q$ - Real orthogonal matrix (colums) $[m\times{n}]$, $n\le{m}$;
$L$ - lower triangular matrix $[m\times{m}]$ with comlex elements:

$$ L =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        l_{1} & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
        l_{2} & l_{1} &  0 &\cdots & 0  \\
        l_{3} & l_{2} &  l_{1} &\cdots & 0  \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
        0 & 0 & l_{3} & l_{2} & l_{1}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the question is.

Comment: why inverse $(A)^{-1}\neq{Q^T}L^{-1}$ because $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: Because $Q$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately, with square $Q$ it doesn't work too

Comment: With spare matrix, orthogonal $Q$ we have $Q^T=Q^{-1}$, and it is true.

Comment: $Q$ - dense, $L$ - spare. pseudo inverse $Q = Q^T$. In my simulation (Matlab) $A^{-1}\neq{Q^TL^{-1}}$